# Menustrip in WPF

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

I am looking for Menu items to slide right side when mouse is focused on the Menu strip(menu strip should be in Vertical style)?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) with the RoutedEvent MouseEnter. Inside the trigger, set up a Storyboard that will animate the TranslateTransform property of MenuItem. Something like this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MenuItem.MouseEnter">
   <EventTrigger.Actions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
         <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
             Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
             From="0" To="100"/>
         </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
   </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```